# Sort data from Microsoft SQL via powershell

Tags: sql-server-2008, networking, powershell

I have the following script that allows me to get MAC Addresses from MS SQL Db.

```
Function Get-MAC ($Server)
{
    $SQLServer = "TVEAPP02" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances! 
    $SQLDBName = "EuropeanMacs"
    $SqlQuery = "select MAC from dbo.tbl_MAC WHERE HOST = '$Server'"

    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

    $SqlConnection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]
}

GET-MAC Computerrname
```

And i get for examples this result:

> GET-MAC 1IT001 2
>
> MAC
>
> ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 F4:CE:46:2C:21:FE
>   F4:CE:46:2C:21:FE

How can i get a 1st or a 2nd MAC from this result?
I mean i want to have result for example in $MAC1 and $MAC2...

Sorry for my english and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

A `SELECT` statement will *not* return items in any specific order unless an `ORDER BY` is used in the query too. If you don't order the set, it is possible that running the query two times will return different values.

In order to retrieve nth element, first check the number of rows returned. A `DataTable` has property `Rows` that contains the count of, well, rows. Like so,

```
$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

After the row count is known (so you don't point to a non-existing row), accessing data is done via row index and column name. Assuming MAC address in row 3 is 46:2C:21:FE:F4:CE, retrieve it. The row index is zero-based, just like table index. Like so,

```
PS C:\> $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[2].MAC
46:2C:21:FE:F4:CE
```

To put two MAC addresses in different variables, just use assignment operator. Like so,

```
PS C:\> $MAC1 = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].MAC
PS C:\> $MAC2 = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[1].MAC
```